# Replace a value with NA in an integer column while retaining the type closest to original

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a Numpy array with arbitrary flat structural data type with some columns as integers, some as `datetime64`, some floats etc...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([(1, -1), (-1, 2)], dtype=[('a', 'i2'), ('b', 'i4')])
```

A Pandas dataframe is directly created from this numpy array precisely following its schema:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(ar)
>>> df
   a  b
0  1 -1
1 -1  2
>>> df.dtypes
a    int16
b    int32
dtype: object
```

Now I want to say replace all -1 values in this data frame to `NA` while retaining the original data types as closely as possible. Basically this:

```
>>> df_with_na = df.replace(-1, pd.NA)
>>> df_with_na
      a     b
0     1  <NA>
1  <NA>     2
```

except that this does not work because the column dtypes were converted to *object*:

```
>>> df_with_na.dtypes
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
```

which does not match the desired result of just mapping `int16` to `Int16`:

```
>>> df_with_na.dtypes
a    Int16
b    Int32
dtype: object
```

Is there a way to convert the `int16` etc whatever blindly to the masked nullable extension types, or preferably even making the `replace` with `NA` to change to the extension type if it wasn't originally, without having to write *yet* another set of lookup tables with all possible extensions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [going ahead and converting all your dtypes to the nullable ones](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) before you do anything to the dataframe:

```py
>>> df.dtypes
a    int16
b    int32
dtype: object
>>> df.convert_dtypes().dtypes
a    Int16
b    Int32
dtype: object
```

You might want to set all those kwargs other than `convert_integer` to `False` to be on the safe side.

Comment: Whoa, how my google-fu has failed me!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I mean someone should probably open a PR to link this method from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. As always pandas **never** fails to surprise me at how **bad** it is.